# Нужна помощь с цепочкой словообразования

Tags: словообразование

Помогите, пожалуйста, определить, от какого слова образовано "втиснуть", и правильно составить словообразовательную цепочку.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно считают начальным глагол несовершенного вида, следовательно: втискивать - втиснуть - суффиксальный способ.

Полная цепочка: тискать - втискивать - втиснуть.

Answer (score 1):

Во главе цепочки, по Тихонову, стоит глагол *тискать*, одно из значений которого, согласно словарю Ефремовой,  "3. Заталкивать, засовывать куда-либо или во что-либо" (https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/254076).

Словообразовательная цепочка для *втиснуть* у Тихонова (Словообразовательный словарь русского языка. М., 1990), выглядит так:

**тискать** —> тис-**ну**-ть —> **в**-тиснуть (приставочный способ словообразования; так же образуются глаголы *про-тиснуть, с-тиснуть*...).

**P.S.**

И далее: (**в**-тиснуть) —> втис*к*-**ива**-ть.

Comment: Не согласна.Тогда уж тискать -втискивать (прист-суфф.) - втиснуть (суфф.) Глагол многозначный. Для значения "заталкивать, засовывать" форма "тиснуть" не пойдёт, это для 1 значения: тискать - мять, сжимать в объятиях, можно и 1 раз тиснуть, сжать. Значение "тискать - заталкивать" отмечают далеко не все словари, оно устарело, сейчас  на грани просторечия, как и "втискать". В словарях для "втиснуть" отмечается глагол несов. вида только "втискивать", а несов. вид по отношению к сов. - первичный. Значит, тискать, втискивать - втиснуть.

Comment: _Людмила: ...несов. вид по отношению к сов. - первичный. Значит, тискать, втискивать - втиснуть_ === Гм... Т. е., по-вашему, в парах, к примеру, выиграть - выигрывать, выдумать - выдумывать, заработать - зарабатывать  **производящими** для _выиграть, выдумать, заработать_ следует считать глаголы _выигрывать, выдумывать, зарабатывать_??? По-моему, всё верно с точностью до наоборот.

Comment: Слава,  у Шведовой в учебнике есть фраза: § 923. Глаголы с суф. -ну-  относятся к сов. виду и мотивируются глаголами несов. вида. https://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/suffiks-nu2-prefiksyi-96138.html  И потом, в этом значении глагол тиснуть что обозначает?   По-моему, без приставки он не существует: один раз тиснуть куда-то? Мне кажется, тиснуть можно статейку  в газете или тиснуть кого-то (один раз сжать), а направленное действие создаётся приставкой.

Comment: Людмила, у Тихонова _тискать - тиснуть_, что не противоречит приведённому Вами параграфу 923 из Шведовой. Что до значения глагола _тиснуть_ — здесь с Вами согласен. Но не согласен с предлагаемой Вами возможностью вести образование глагола _втиснуть_ от _втискивать_. Ни одного примера с похожим образованием я не знаю. Думаю, и Вы не сможете найти — ни у Шведовой, ни у кого другого..

Comment: Видимо, для приставочного глагола однонапраленного действия суффикс -НУ- непродуктивный, к тому же это разговорное слово. А вот хворать-прихварывать-прихворнуть или хворать-хворнуть-прихворнуть? А лист-листать - перелистывать-перелистнуть или листать-листнуть-перелистнуть? Наверно, словообразование разговорных глаголов всё-таки неоднозначно.